# type conversion data printing Error in C lang

Tags: c, type-conversion

In C

```
int n=100;
printf("%d", (int)(sqrt((double)n)));
```

When I use this code it prints the correct answer (10).

But following code always prints 0

```
int n; 
int max = (int)(sqrt((double)n));
printf("%d", max);
```

Why are the answers are different ?

Comment: `n` will be having indeterminate value, what else do you except it to print?

Answer (score 1):

```
int n=100;
printf("%d", (int)(sqrt((double)n)));
```

In this case, the value of n is known i.e, 100. So `sqrt((double)n)` returns the correct value.

```
int n; 
int max = (int)(sqrt((double)n));
printf("%d", max);
```

Here, the variable n is uninitialized. The variable could be holding an indeterminate value depending upon whether it is declared locally (inside a block, in which case the value of n would be a junk value) or globally (outside a block, in which case the value of n would be zero). Always initialize your variables to avoid such errors.

Comment: Small note: *"inside a block, in which case the value of n would be a junk value"* Since `n` has automatic storage duration, and its address is never taken, it is more likely *undefined behaviour* (C17 §6.3.2.1 p2), which in this case has resulted in junk value. But anyway, your advice is correct.

Comment: @user694733 Yeah. That's what I actually meant. Appreciate your input.